# Is it possible to group Observables in an object instead of an array?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have several `Observables`, and I want do something similar to `Promise.all` for them (perhaps `.forkJoin`)

```
const two = Observable.of(2);
const three = Observable.of(3);
const four = Observable.of(4);
```

But as a result I want to have an object instead of array, because I don't want to access the data by numeric keys.

```
.subscribe(result => {  
  const two = result[0] // I don't want this
  const three = result[1]
  const four = result[2]
})
```

What I'd like to see is to do something like

```
 .subscribe(result => {
    const two = result.two // this is much better
    const three = result.three
    const four = result.four
  })
```

For sure I can do something like this:

```
Observable
  .forkJoin(two, three, four)
  .flatMap(result  => Observable.of({two: result [0], three: result [1], four: result [2]}))
```

But eventually it's the same - I will get data based on number keys.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

---

**P.S.** One of the possible [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51986382/930170) solution - is to use destructuring:

```
const [two, three, four] = [...result]
```

This is feels much better, but doesn't provide any help if somebody will change the order if `.forkJoin`:

```
  //was
  .forkJoin(two, three, four)
  //become
  .forkJoin(two, four, three)
  // ...
  .subscribe(([two, three, four]) => {
    // say hello to "magic errors"
  })
```

This is my main point - to avoid such kind of "hard to find" bugs

Comment: Have you considered destructuring instead?

Comment: @jordrake Do you mean doing `const [two, three, four] = [...result]`? Well, it's much better, yes, but honestly that doesn't helps if somebody would change observables order in `forkJoin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written a utility function that enables you do this in `RxJS 6`. I am not sure what version you are using but hopefully it can be supported there.

```
function forkJoinObj(obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const values = Object.values(obj);

  return forkJoin(values).pipe(map(result => result.reduce((acc, next, index) => {
    acc[keys[index]] = next;
    return acc;
  }, {})));
}
```

See example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dvrff8

Answer (score 3):

There's no build-in RxJS operator to do this but you can use the following syntax:

```
.subscribe(([two, three, four]) => {
  // ...
})
```

...or this:

```
.subscribe(results => {
  const [two, three, four] = results
}
```

Comment: It's same as @jordrake mentioned - it's much better but still depends on order

Comment: The order is guaranteed by `forkJoin` to be always the same.

Comment: Yes, but my point is about code maintainability - if someone would add/remove or change order of something inside `.forkJoin` - well, `.subscribe()` function will be broken. I'm actually looking for a way to avoid it